# Swagger editor: Cannot set content type in multipart request

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I'm using online Swagger Editor with OpenAPI 3.0 and I have to create a definition of file upload. The problem is in CURL that editor generates.

In the case when file extension is "unknown" (like .abc) editor doesn't generate type

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:xxxx/files/upload" -H "accept: */*" -H 
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "upload=@text.abc;type="
```

It ignores contentType defined by YAML if extension is "known" :

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:xxxx/files/upload" -H "accept: */*" -H 
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "upload=@text.txt;type=text/plain"
```

should be (I need):

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:xxxx/files/upload" -H "accept: */*" -H 
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "upload=@text.txt; type=application/octet-stream"
```

The YAML is:

```
/files/upload:
    post:
    summary: upload file
    operationId: uploadFile
    description: this API is for file upload
    requestBody:
      content:
        multipart/form-data:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              upload:
                type: string
                format: binary
          encoding:
            upload:
              contentType: application/octet-stream
    responses:
      200:
        description: Operation performed succesfuly.
      400:
        description: Operation failed
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your definition looks correct. File a bug or feature request in the Swagger UI repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new/choose.

Comment: Did you create an issue in the repo ? If so can you share the link ?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot. Our company firewall blocks access to githab